# Show that this ideal cannot be generated by 2 elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y$ be the curve given parametrically by $x=t^3, y = t^4, z = t^5$. Show that $I(Y)$ is a prime ideal of height $2$ in $k[x,y,z]$ which cannot be generated by two elements.

Obviously $(x^4-y^3,x^5-z^3) \subseteq I(Y)$, but these ideals can't be equal because the one on the right is generated by two elements. So, what is the prime $I(Y)$? And how can i show its height is precisely 2?

Comment: $k[t^3,t^4,t^5]\simeq k[x,y,z]/I(Y)$. Now count the dimensions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96691/height-and-minimal-number-of-generators-of-an-ideal/306719?r=SearchResults#306719

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To prove that an ideal cannot be generated by two elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780875/to-prove-that-an-ideal-cannot-be-generated-by-two-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, implicitization is given by taking the ideal $I=\langle x-t^3,y-t^4,z-t^5\rangle$ w.t.r. the lex ordering $t>x>y>z$ and eliminating $t$ by considering the first elimination ideal $I_1 = I\cap k[x,y,z]$, which is given by the elimination theorem via its Gröbner basis $G_1 = G\cap k[x,y,z]$ where $G$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$. I've performed the calculation in Singular giving $G$ as follows:

$y^5-z^4,xz-y^2,xy^3-z^3, x^2y-z^2, x^3-yz, tz-x^2,ty-z, tx-y, t^3-x$.

Comment: So does it mean that to generate the ideal we need all the polynomials on that list that don't have a $t$?

Comment: @José Right. But notice that some generators are superfluous.

Comment: It's a result by Herzog that an ideal like this in $k[x,y,z]$ is generated by either 2 or 3 elements. So the exercise implies it must have 3 generators