# Number of generators in an ideal product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Following a quick search here (and on Google), I could find a lot of questions related to heights of and number of generators of an ideal (such as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96691/height-and-minimal-number-of-generators-of-an-ideal)). However I've not dealt with much commutative algebra so the techniques used (and many of the definitions, too) are totally new to me, and thus I don't know if the following question is trivial or not:

> Given that the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ has $\alpha$ generators and the ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ has $\beta$ generators (both of which are the least amount respectively), what can we say about the least number of generators for the product $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$?

I'm only working with ideals of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ where $K$ is some number field, if there is a more specific answer in this case. From what I've done so far, it seems that the number of generators for $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ is a factor of $\alpha\beta$ (only because I haven't found any counterexamples yet), though I have no idea if this is true or not, nor if there is a quick way of determining how many generators such a product would have.

Comment: Not strictly an answer to the question you asked, but: in a Dedekind domain (such as $\mathcal{O}_K$ for $K$ a number field), all ideals can be generated by either one or two elements.

Comment: @Billy Interesting, I will look into this (I have not come across Dedekind domains, either). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment into something that looks more like a rough answer, because you've actually stumbled upon one of the most fundamental questions in algebraic number theory!

If $K$ is an algebraic number field, then its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain, and it's a standard fact that every ideal in a Dedekind domain is either principal or generated by two elements.

One fundamental question of algebraic number theory is: when can elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ be written uniquely as a product of prime elements (just like in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{Z}$)?

Now, the reason we *care* about ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ in the first place is that they behave like numbers, but more nicely: it turns out that *ideals* in $\mathcal{O}_K$ can always be written uniquely as a product of prime *ideals*. And it's not too hard to show from here that uniqueness of prime factorisation for *elements* happens precisely when all ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ are principal. (Very roughly: you can interpret the ideal $(a)$ and the element $a$ as meaning the same thing, but there's no sensible way of interpreting a non-principal ideal $(a,b)$ as a single element.)

In fact, we can construct an object $C_K$, called the *ideal class group* of $\mathcal{O}_K$ (or of $K$), that tells us how badly $\mathcal{O}_K$ fails to be a principal ideal domain. It's a group, as its name suggests; and every ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is associated to an element of $C_K$ in a way that respects the multiplication (so if $I\lhd \mathcal{O}_K$ is associated to $[I]\in C_K$, and likewise $J$ to $[J]$, then $IJ$ is associated to $[I][J]$, or in other words $[IJ] = [I][J]$), and such that **$I$ is principal if and only if $[I]$ is the identity element of $C_K$**.

So let's think about your question in this setting.

- *If* $C_K$ happens to be the trivial group, then all ideals are principal *anyway*.
- If $C_K$ is non-trivial, then there are non-principal ideals. Let's take a principal ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ and a non-principal ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ (so that $[\mathfrak{a}]$ is the identity element of $C_K$, and $[\mathfrak{b}]$ is *not* the identity element). Then $[\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}] = [\mathfrak{a}][\mathfrak{b}] = [\mathfrak{b}]$ is a non-identity element, so $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ isn't principal.
- What if $C_K$ is non-trivial, and $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are both non-principal? Then we need to know something about $C_K$. For instance, if $|C_K| = 2$, then there's only one non-identity element, and it must be the same as $[\mathfrak{a}]$ and $[\mathfrak{b}]$; and $[\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}] = [\mathfrak{a}]^2 = \mathrm{id}$, so $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ is principal. But if $|C_K| \geq 3$, then we might have $[\mathfrak{a}] = [\mathfrak{b}]^{-1}$ (in which case their product is the identity) or $[\mathfrak{a}] = [\mathfrak{b}]$ (in which case it isn't). Here we need to know more about the ideals themselves.

So, the crucial question is: how do we calculate $C_K$? Or, at least, *some* information about it - say, the order of the group $|C_K|$, often called the *class number* of $K$?

The simple answer is: usually, we can't. We've managed to do a lot of simple cases (e.g. here is [a list of number fields whose ideal class group is trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one)), but for most examples of number fields $K$, this is still a hard open question. Any book on algebraic number theory, at this point, will probably spend several chapters developing basic techniques in this direction, such as the [Minkowski bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound). Here are some [worked examples](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf). I'll leave you to read around.

Comment: I have actually come across most of what you mention --- my question was motivated by the fact that I'm currently trying to determine the class group for lots of different number fields! The links are certainly helpful, and I shall look through the worked examples for more help. Thank you again!